# Customize App Bar Color Only in Dark Mode

Tags: android, material-design

I am using material theme in my app. As specified on the material website [here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/),
the app bar uses `ColorPrimary` in the light theme and `ColorSurface` in the dark theme. I would like to change the color of the app bar in the dark theme. I can obviously do this by changing the `ColorSurface` attribute only in the dark theme, but then it affects other components that use this attribute too like Dialogs, TimePickers etc. Is there any way I can **only** change the color of the app bar in the dark theme?

Answer (score 4):

If I am sure, you want to change the background color of appbar in dark theme, then if so, make a new style resource file with night qualifier, declare your style of the app and override 'actionBarStyle' something like this,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Solid">
<item name="background">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

I hope this is what you want...

Comment: Best answer. It helped me. Is some tutorial to learn how to change colors in themes? I never know from where I have to take parent... .

Comment: For material theming, I would suggest [this](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#theming-the-top-app-bar). And for a parent to inherit styles, there no specific documentation. Most of the time for me, it's searching and going inside the widget style itself. @wenus

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but if anyone is looking for some form of solution the following worked for me.

I'm not sure what the style based solution to this is, but programmatically you can do the following (which i found in this article about the daynight theme: [Using the DayNight Theme](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94))

You would use the theme parent as per below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

And then where ever you want to check and make changes you can use the following snippets

**Java**

```
//the & here is a bitwise AND operator as opposed to &&
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode
    & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK

switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're in day time

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're at night!
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
             );
             break;

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
        // We don't know what mode we're in, assume notnight

}
```

**Kotlin**

```
//again using a bitwise AND operator here
var currentNightMode: Int = this.resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK

when(currentNightMode){
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO ->{
         // Night mode is not active, we're in day time
    }

    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES ->{
        // Night mode is not active, we're in day time
         supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(
                    ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent, null))
         )
    }

    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED ->{
    // We don't know what mode we're in, assume notnight
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not allow me to customize the color of my app bar, only to set the mode to day or night.

Comment: I understood your question as using light and dark theme for your app and changing the appbar only for dark, which the above code does. It simply detects whether dark or light mode is active and allows you to act upon it, it doesnt set anything.

If you wish to change the actionBar colour you can do it with the code above `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable... ` etc
Or provide me with a little more detail and i'll help you out (i.e appbar layout with toolbar? what theme are you using?)